# AWS billing: how to dispose of unneeded volumes and AMIs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a project in development on AWS EC2 and it will be dormant for a few months.
I want to shut down all resources to reduce costs, and keep only the minimal set of resources around. I have a bunch of instances, volumes, AMIs, snapshots that i'm being charged for. 
I'm trying to figure out how they're all linked together, which ones I can destroy, and in what order to do things?

I am attaching screenshots of the different panels. For the sake of specificity, let's say I want to be able to revive the instance called `tow_apachesolr`. Do I need to keep it's linked volume?

**Instances**

[image: EC2 instances]

**Volumes**

[image: Volumes]

**AMIs**

[image]

**Billing**

[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 1):

This is truly a question for Amazon themselves, but from what I understand, when you have an AMI you *must* have a linked volume so there's a place for the data to be stored. Storage is fairly cheap.

I do however see an unused elastic IP. Get rid of that to shave another couple bucks.

Answer (score 1):

These bash lines use the ec2 tools to get all snapshots (with the CreateImage description which is used by the AMI creator of the AWS Console) and links them against the actual AMIs. So every snapshot which isn't used by an AMI anymore will be deleted:

```
for s in $(
comm -23 <(echo $(ec2-describe-snapshots --filter "description=*CreateImage*" --region us-east-1 | grep SNAPSHOT | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq) | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo $(ec2-describe-images --region us-east-1 | grep BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq) | tr ' ' '\n') | tr '\n' ' ')
do
echo Deleting snapshot $s
ec2-delete-snapshot --region us-east-1 $s
done
```

As you can see we use us-east1 as an example. Just change this if you need this in any other AWS region.
With this you're able to delete all old snapshots which were created for AMIs you already deleted (we create many AMIs and so we need to delete the old snapshots fairly often to save money here).

Hope this helps!